# CRM - Citizen Relationship Management cloud solution

Tags: database, cloud, storage

I am starting a political mandate next month, and I would like to store various opinions and events in a (relational?) database online.

To make things clearer, I wish I can find a ready to use tool (not too expensive or free, and preferably open source) to

1. Maintain a list of politicians in the area.
2. Maintain a list of events in our local political life
3. Track political themes over time
4. Maintain a list of opinions from politicians about those themes
5. Track participation of politicians to events, like local councils
6. Link events and opinions to media articles, pictures and/or sound
7. Track party subscriptions of the politicians
8. ...

Of course, part of this information should be stored on the fly during meetings (like who is here tonight and who is not?), while other bits might be updated off site (like summaries of speeches).

Does anyone now about a solution that would fit these needs? It might be called Citizen Relationship Management, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Online could definitely do all of that and more.  It is on demand and you can get a free one month trial here - http://crm.dynamics.com/en-us/home

Dynamics CRM has been marketed as xRM for a while now for its ability to be easily customized to track any type of relationships.

Please take a look at some of my previous answers for more information on what it can do -

[Any CRM platforms that have API access and an easy migration from Salesforce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192594/any-crm-platforms-that-have-api-access-and-an-easy-migration-from-salesforce/6195622#6195622)

[Can I use Dynamics CRM as a Shopping Website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006187/can-i-use-dynamics-crm-as-a-shopping-website/7006612#7006612)

Comment: Thank you Cole. Looks a little bit like advertisement, but it seems interesting to investigate CRM solutions, be it MS, or any other. Sorry I noticed your answer so late (presumably forgot to check the notify box...).

Comment: No problem Vincent.  Its true that I am biased towards Dynamics CRM because I work heavily with it but all of the information I have given is accurate and I do believe it is the most flexible of all the primary CRM applications on the market today.